# How to show the minimum and maximum price?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a view that shows the details of a specific conference (name, description, price, etc).

To show each info I use: `{{$conf->name}}, {{$conf->descrption}}, etc.`

But in the case of price, the conference don't have a price. Each conference can have many registration types. Each registration type have a specific price.

The price is a column of the RegistrationType table, not Conference table.

In the conference details view I want to show the price range, for example, if the conference has 3 registration types and the minimum price of one of the registration types is "0" and the maximum is "10" I want to show in the view the range of the registration types of that conference, that is "0-10".

But I'm not understanding what is the process to be possible to show in the view the range price of the registration types that exist for a specific conference, do you know?

The Conference model and RegistrationType model are like:

**Conference model:**

```
class Event extends Model
{
// A conference has many registration types
    public function registrationTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
    }
}
```

**RegistrationType Model:**

```
class RegistrationType extends Model
{
    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do something like $conference->registrationTypes() and get a collection of all registration types. You could also wrap this in a helper method on the Conference (Event) model itself to calculate the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way (assuming that Event is in fact your Conference class) :

```
class Conference extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['price_range'];

    public function registrationTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
    }

    public function getPriceRangeAttribute() {
        return $this->registrationTypes()->get()->min('price') . ' - ' . $this->registrationTypes()->get()->max('price');
        /* The first answer :
         * return $this->registrationTypes()->min('price') . ' - ' . $this->registrationTypes()->max('price');
         * should also do it, and could even be better, because no 
         * other results than the actual min and max are returned,
         * no collection fetched ! */
    }
}
```

Here you tell Laravel to [appends](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) the **price_range** attribute to every instance of **Conference**. The **price_range** attribute is returned by the **getPriceRangeAttribute** [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) who check for the minimum and maximum found in the price column for every registrationType linked (returned by the hasMany relation) to your Conference.

Comment: Thanks, but like that in the frontend using "{{$conf->price_range}}" appears "string(148) "select min(`price`) as aggregate from `registration_types` where `registration_types`.`conf_id` = ? and `registration_types`.`conf_id` is not null" string(148) "select max(`price`) as aggregate from `registration_types` where `registration_types`.`conf_id` = ? and `registration_types`.`conf_id` is not null" 2 - 10", instead of show the price range. Do you know why?

Comment: Now it appears "Call to a member function get() on float" on "        return $this->registrationTypes()->min('price')->get() . ' - ' . $this->registrationTypes()->max('price')->get();".

Comment: Reedited. I belive the get method has to be called before the min and max methods

Comment: Thanks, but like that it appears again the same issue: "string(124) "select * from `registration_types` where `registration_types`.`conf_id` = ? and `registration_types`.`conf_id` is not null" string(124) "select * from `registration_types` where `registration_types`.`conf_id` = ? and `registration_types`.`conf_id` is not null" 2 - 10".

Comment: Are you logging your query or relations somewhere ? With a print_r or something ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167419/discussion-between-quentin-petel-and-johnz).

Answer (score 0):

The sample code would be something like:

```
class Event extends Model
{
    public function registrationTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
    }

    public function priceRangeAttribute() {
        $registrationTypes = $this->registrationTypes();
        return $this->orderPriceRanges($registrationTypes);
    }

    private function orderPriceRanges($registrationTypes) {
        // process the collection and format the different prices (0, 2, 10)
        // into a price range like 0-10
    }
}
```

You would then access it like $conf->price_range.

Comment: Thanks, but like that is appearing "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::registrationPriceRange". Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry, I'm writing it off the top of my head. I updated the example by renaming the method to be an accessor https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor and also the way you can call it.

Comment: Thanks!! In the orderPriceRanges I have  private function orderPriceRanges($registrationTypes) {
        foreach ($registrationTypes as $rtype){
            return "price";
        }
    } to test but in the view nothing appears. Do you know why?

Comment: Try to debug what the values of the variables are by using a debugger or simple `dd($registrationTypes);` calls.

Comment: You can also use collection methods on the $registrationTypes as it should be a Collection. For example you can `$registrationTypes->sortBy('price')->pluck('price');` to get ordered prices. Then you can `return $orderedPrices->min() . "-" . $orderedPrices->max()`.

Comment: Thanks. I dont know why but the price still dont appears. It seems that the method is not called, with this "private function orderPriceRanges($registrationTypes) {

    
        dd($registrationTypes);
      
    }" dont shows nothing.

Comment: With "public function priceRangeAttribute() {
        $registrationTypes = $this->registrationTypes();
        dd($registrationTypes);}" also dont shows nothing.